# Showing different Pagertemplates for Top and Bottom Pager

Tags: asp.net

I've got a normal ASP.NET gridview with a custom pagertemplate and would like to display a different content in top pager than in the bottom pager.

Imaging you want to display a normal Pager in to Bottom Pager and the total number of record inside the top pager.

Now, there are a couple of solutions I could think of:

- Detecting the RowIndex or RowType of the current Row. (This doesn't work, since i'am in a Template)
- Somehow set a different Template for the Top / Bottom Pager. (Is that even possible?)

What else could I try? Has anyone done somehting similar?

Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ovveride the initialize pager method of the grid view to create different top/bottom pagers. But doing so would involve generating HTML in the codebehind which is a pain.

```
protected override void InitializePager(GridViewRow row, 
                                            int columnSpan, 
                                            PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)
{
//if (this.TopPagerRow == null && 
if (this.Controls[0].Controls.Count == 0 && 
   (this.PagerSettings.Position == PagerPosition.Top || 
    this.PagerSettings.Position == PagerPosition.TopAndBottom))
{
    InitializeTopPager(row, columnSpan, pagedDataSource);
}
else
{
    base.InitializePager(row, columnSpan, pagedDataSource);
    InitializeBottomPager(row, columnSpan, pagedDataSource);
}
```

}

Ref: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28910/Custom-GridView-with-Paging-and-Filtering

I'm not sure of a slick way you can do it with a top/bottom pager template